# сайты на HTML CSS JS вместе с C#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

Можно ли создавать сайты с front-end с помощью html css js, а в качестве back-end языка программирования использовать C#? Знаю, что для C# есть ASP.NET, но ещё до изучения шарпа интересовался вёрсткой html css js. Учить ASP.NET не хочется, больше тянет в сторону html css js. Так вот, можно ли использовать для back-end языка C#, вместо условного PHP или Python, и если можно, стоит ли, или лучше писать back-end на PHP или Python?

Comment: Капец тух хаос в голове....  "Можно ли  в качестве back-end использовать C#?" ......"Знаю, что для C# есть ASP.NET"....... " Учить ASP.NET не хочется" ...... "можно ли использовать для back-end языка C#"

Comment: Да, можно использовать C#.  Лучше ли: кто как хочет, тот так и др.....делает.

Comment: [Tutorial: Call an ASP.NET Core web API with JavaScript](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: "тянет в сторону html css js." --- ну так учите их и идите в фронтендеры. к чему этот вопрос?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , соглашусь с вами, в голове полный хаос, сейчас хочу определится какую именно отрасль программирования выбрать и что для этого учить. До этого учил шарп, но хочется попробовать что-то другое. Может научится делать сайты и попробовать себя в роли Fullstack-developer на фрилансе, может идти в фронтендеры, может в бэкенд с уже какими никакими да знаниями в C#. В общем, пробую разные отрасли пока не найду ту, в которую хотелось бы быть.

Comment: Фулл-стек разработчики - это те кто сначала стали фронтендерами, но потом поняли свою ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можно ли создавать сайты с front-end с помощью html css js, а в качестве back-end языка программирования использовать C#?

Да. Stackoverflow тому доказательство

> Знаю, что для C# есть ASP.NET

Да, всё верно, и не только он.

> Учить ASP.NET не хочется, больше тянет в сторону html css js.

Не учите ASP.NET, учите и углубляйтесь в js и идите во фронтенд разработчики. Развивайтесь в этой области.

> Можно ли использовать для back-end языка C#, вместо условного PHP или Python, и если можно

Можно. См. первый пункт

> или лучше писать back-end на PHP или Python?

Кому что нравится. Это субъективно. Языков для бэка больше чем 3-4 (не только есть php, python, C# и Java). Их вообще десятки и сотни. Так что если хочется, можно изучать любой по вкусу.

**Кстати есть nodejs. Так что любителю js  можно изучать его для бэка**

Comment: Спасибо за вашу помощь, вы поправили мне хаос в голове.

Comment: @Programmer_XD кстати, если развиваться как фронтенд но нравится типизация, то можно рассмотреть typescript. Это js но типизированный